# Integral Zero on a $\pi$-System Implies $f=0$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f\in\mathcal{L}_1$. Assume $\int_Af=0$, $\forall A\in\mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\pi$-System such that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathscr{A}$, where ``$\sigma(\mathcal{A})$" means $\sigma$-Algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$. How does this imply $f=0$ a.e.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Write $$f =f^+ - f^-;$$ here $f^+$ and $f^-$ denote the positive and negative part of $f$, respectively. By assumption, the (non-negative) measures 
   $$\mu(A) := \int_A f^+ \, d\mu \qquad \nu(A) := \int_A f^- \, d\mu$$
   coincide on the generator $\mathcal{A}$. Deduce from the uniqueness of measure theorem that $\nu = \mu$ on $\mathscr{A}$.
2. By step 1, $$\int_A f \, d\mu = 0$$ for all $A \in \mathscr{A}$. Consider $A = \{f >0\}$ and $A = \{f<0\}$ to conclude $f=0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

Comment: Thankyou. Beautiful answer.