# How to prove f=0 almost everywhere in this case?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, almost-everywhere

The Lebesgue integrable function $f$ on $[a,b]$ satisfies the following condition:

$\int_a^xf d\mu=0$ for any $x \in [a,b]$

I want to prove that $f=0$ a.e., so I tried $f=f_+-f_-$ , where $f_+=\max \{f,0\} $ and $f_-=-\min\{f,0\}$, and I tried to prove that the integration on $[a,b]$ of $f_+$ and $f_-$ is both zero, but it doesn't work. Is there any other approach to the proof? I already know that $\int_x^yf d\mu=0$ for any $[x,y] \subset [a,b]$.

p.s. I'm just a beginner of real analysis, so I don't know anything but basic measure theory and lebesgue integration.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1527486/

Comment: Is there any way to approach this proof with only using basic measure theory/integration/convergence theorems?

Comment: The linked question/answer does only use basic measure theory.

Comment: @saz I think the linked answer does not give directly what the asker wants, i.e from the assumptions of the current problem it only (directly) follows that $\int\limits_{x_1}^{x_2}{fd\mu}=0$ for any  interval $[x_1,x_2]$ but not for any Lebesgue measurable set in $\Sigma([a,b])$

Answer (score 0):

Denote $F(x) = \int_a^x f(y) \textrm{d}\mu$, then we have $F(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and so $F'= 0$.
So by Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem we have a.s. $f = F' = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm afraid I did not learn Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem yet.