# Integrability requirement to prove $f = 0$ a.e.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

I want to show that for measurable $f$, $\int\limits_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ implies that $f = 0$ a.e.

From a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527486/integral-zero-on-a-pi-system-implies-f-0), I can see that $\int\limits_{B} f^+(t) dt = \int\limits_{B} f^-(t) dt$ for all Borel sets $B$. However, my concern is that unless we assume that $f$ is in $\mathcal{L}^1$, we cannot conclude $f = 0$ a.e. since $\int_B f^+(t)$ might be $\infty$. Is $f \in \mathcal{L}^1$ a necessary assumption?

Comment: In order for the assumed equality $\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm dt=0$ to make sense, it is necessary that $f$ be integrable on $(-\infty,x)$ for any given $x\in\mathbb R$. It follows that $f(t)=0$ for almost every $t\in(-\infty,x)$. Since $x\in\mathbb R$ is arbitrary, you can conclude (how exactly?) that $f(t)=0$ for almost every $t\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: For your last paragraph, all your $0 < X_i < \theta$ are bounded, hence $0 < T(X) < \theta$ is bounded, so it's automatically in $L^1$ without additional assumptions.

Comment: @triple_sec I think I see, we can just take a countable union of $(-\infty, x)$ that equals $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @NikhilGhosh Yes. We have
\begin{align*}
&\lambda(\{t\in\mathbb R\,|\,f(t)\neq 0\})\\
{}={}&\lambda\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\{t\in(-\infty,n)\,|\,f(t)\neq 0\}\right)\\
{}\leq{}&\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\lambda(\{t\in(-\infty,n)\,|\,f(t)\neq 0\})\\
{}={}&0,
\end{align*}
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 3):

For $x<y$, 
\begin{align*}
\int_{x}^{y}f(t)dt=\int_{-\infty}^{y}f(t)dt-\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt=0,
\end{align*}
so for any $r>0$, 
\begin{align*}
\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(t)dt=0,
\end{align*}
we know that for any locally integrable $f$, for a.e. $x$ we have
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(t)dt,
\end{align*}
the result follows immediately.